Why is a SQLite database 440% bigger with WITHOUT ROWID
I create a table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image_table
("name" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "data" BLOB) WITHOUT ROWID;

and I prepare the statement:
INSERT INTO image_table (name, data) VALUES (?1, ?2);

And then I bind a 1000 byte blob to ?2 and the name + i to ?1 (so name1, name2 and so on) for the key. And I iterate 100'000 times. The key name whatever is kind of negligable, between 5 and 10 bytes, but in total it comes to 100'000 * 1000 = 100MB roughly.
If I do this with WITHOUT ROWID the resulting size of the file is 444MB. If I don't put WITHOUT ROWID, the resulting size is about 100MB. Vacuuming didn't really do anything other than shrink the size from 444MB to about 338MB. That's an enormous difference and I just found this out by accident when someone pointed out they couldn't reproduce the results I was getting. I thought WITHOUT ROWID was intended to make things MORE efficient by eliminating an unnecessary index.
Edit: Also, having WITHOUT ROWID makes it twice as slow. I think I'm not ever using WITHOUT ROWID.
Edit again: If I make the blob size 10 bytes instead of 1000 WITHOUT ROWID is about the same speed and half the size. Wow this is really confusing.

If you have any indexes on the table, the full key string has to be stored in them instead of a compact rowid integer. That can definitely cause some bloat.

From documentation:
https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html

A WITHOUT ROWID table uses a different data design

The official documentation lists "less storage space" as one of the advantages of using a WIHOUT ROWID table, but at the same time points out that when individual rows are large, the cost of using another kind of b-tree can outweigh the savings:

WITHOUT ROWID tables are implemented using ordinary B-Trees with content stored on both leaves and intermediate nodes. Storing content in intermediate nodes causes each intermediate node entry to take up more space on the page

